# Favorites filter highlights all the questions in the unanswered queue

Tags: discussion, tag-watching

My favorite tags are html and sql-server. If I go to the Unanswered questions and filter by the html tag, all of the questions are highlighted. I don't like this because I already know that all of the questions have one of my favorites tags, I filtered based on my favorite tags.
[image: All Highlighting]

Does this drive anyone else crazy? Also, are there settings or anything that I can change to stop this from happening?

Comment: For the first screenshot, what is the url? Actually, go ahead and post the urls for both screenshots.

Comment: @gunr2171 The first screenshot is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html the second is http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/html

Comment: Have you ignored PHP?  And, if not, WHY NOT?

Comment: @Will I have trained my eyes to glaze over when they see those letters next to each other anyway. I have ignored PHP so much that I don't even need the ignoring feature.

Comment: @Jenn: Am thinking [watched-tag] + [ignored-tag] results in no style change?

Comment: This behavior is logical, as far as I am concerned. What use would it be if you filter by one of your favourite tags and *everything* gets highlighted? It would not make sense because you already know you are in a list that you tagged as "interesting". So, in this sub-list, all your *other* tags are now highlighted.

Comment: @Jongware that's exactly what I am complaining about. I like that my other tags are highlighted. I don't like that in the unanswered questions all of the questions are highlighted. The second image is a screenshot of what is happening right now.

Comment: @Will an ignored tag has absolutely no effect.

Comment: @Jenn: Not true.  Ignored tags will cause a question to have the *tag-ignored* style applied to them, which causes them to fade somewhat.  I [wrote a stackapp to take advantage of this](http://stackapps.com/questions/4211/automatically-hide-ignored-questions).  If that's what you meant.  If not, self-promotion.

Comment: @Will no, I meant that it has no effect for solving this problem.

Comment: What is your list of favorite tags?  Are any of your other favorites also tagged on these questions?

Comment: @jmstoker My favorites is html, sql-server, and autohotkey. I filtered for html questions and none of my other favorite tags are tagged in these questions.