# Why aren't questions with my favorite tags highlighted?

Tags: support, tags

As you can see,

[image]

When I clicked for JavaScript specific tags, only a couple were highlighted despite being tagged as JavaScript.

You can see my favorite tags here,

[image]

What is going on with this? Is there a special case that does not highlight tags for me? I don't have any ignored tags either.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inconsistent highlighting of favorite questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261442/inconsistent-highlighting-of-favorite-questions)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Since all questions there will be JavaScript, it's unhelpful if they are all highlighted.  You will most likely know if it's your favorite already.

It shows when your favorite tags *not including the current tag* are tagged for the question.  This is much more helpful because you can actually distinguish between questions.

In the example you showed, one of the highlighted questions had [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery), which is another one of your favorites aside from JavaScript.  That's why it was highlighted.

Comment: Oh wow, how did I miss that...

Comment: Now if that worked on all tabs: [Favorites filter highlights all the questions in the unanswered queue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261442/favorites-filter-highlights-all-the-questions-in-the-unanswered-queue)

Comment: Yea, it must be a bug.